# How to create multiple form submit buttons with alternate routes in ZF2

Tags: forms, zend-framework2, submit-button

In ZF2, how do you create multiple submit buttons that each lead to different routes?  In the [Forms and actions chaper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html) of the ZF2 tutorial, a form is created with a single submit button with the label “Go” that processes the input data and returns to the index page (route).  Where do we put the pertinent scripts if we wanted four buttons:

- `Save` action: saves user input, route: return to current page
- `Save and Close` action: saves user input, route: return to index (Album)
- `Clear` action: no action, route: return to current page
- `Close` action: no action, route: return to index (Album)

I assume the buttons are created like this:

```
namespace Album\Form;

class AlbumForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null)
    {

        // ... //

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'savebutton',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Save',
                'id' => 'savebutton',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'save_closebutton',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Save & Close',
                'id' => 'save_closebutton',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'clearbutton',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Clear',
                'id' => 'clearbutton',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'closebutton',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Close',
                'id' => 'closebutton',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

This is what the edit action looks like with only one submit button:

```
// module/Album/src/Album/Controller/AlbumController.php:
//...

    // Add content to this method:
    public function editAction()
    {
        $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
        if (!$id) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', array(
                'action' => 'add'
            ));
        }
        $album = $this->getAlbumTable()->getAlbum($id);

        $form  = new AlbumForm();
        $form->bind($album);
        $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Edit');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $this->getAlbumTable()->saveAlbum($form->getData());

                // Redirect to list of albums
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
            }
        }

        return array(
            'id' => $id,
            'form' => $form,
        );
    }
//...
```

Since pairs of buttons have the same form action and pairs of buttons have the same route, I image we want to add two if statements somewhere here, unless a switch statement is better.

Answer (score 0):

Quick 'n dirty way to do what you need:

```
public function editAction()
{
    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    if (!$id) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', array(
            'action' => 'add'
        ));
    }
    $album = $this->getAlbumTable()->getAlbum($id);

    $form  = new AlbumForm();
    $form->bind($album);
    $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Edit');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {

                $input = $form->getData();

                if (!empty($input['save_closebutton'])) {

                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', array(
                        'controller' => 'AlbumController',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ));

                }

        }
    }

    return array(
        'id' => $id,
        'form' => $form,
    );
}
```